# Copy a Nullable property to a non-Nullable version using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am writing code to transform one object to another using reflection...

It's in progress but I think it would boil down to the following where we trust both properties have the same type:

```
    private void CopyPropertyValue(object source, string sourcePropertyName, object target, string targetPropertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo sourceProperty = source.GetType().GetProperty(sourcePropertyName);
        PropertyInfo targetProperty = target.GetType().GetProperty(targetPropertyName);
        targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceProperty.GetValue(source));
    }
```

*However* I have the additional issue that the source type might be Nullable and the target type not. e.g `Nullable<int>` => `int`. In this case I need to make sure it still works and some sensible behaviour is performed e.g. NOP or set the default value for that type.

What might this look like?

Comment: Maybe I'm just crazy but knowing the underlying problem it seems like it could be solved expression trees in a better way

Comment: I don't follow, please feel free to provide an answer!

Comment: well I mean that you could explain what you're trying to solve, not how you want to solve what's unknown to us...

Comment: No, I mean I don't follow what you mean by "expression trees" in this context. The scenario is I have two unrelated classes but a mapping exists  e.g X.name => Y.shortName, etc. And I want to define this transform mapping at run-time not compile-time. Basically like using XSLT but for C# objects.

Comment: What about `MapPropertyTo(x => x.name, y => y.shortName)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that `GetValue` returns a *boxed* representation, which will be a null reference for a null value of the nullable type, it's easy to detect and then handle however you want:

```
private void CopyPropertyValue(
    object source,
    string sourcePropertyName,
    object target,
    string targetPropertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo sourceProperty = source.GetType().GetProperty(sourcePropertyName);
    PropertyInfo targetProperty = target.GetType().GetProperty(targetPropertyName);
    object value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
    if (value == null && 
        targetProperty.PropertyType.IsValueType &&
        Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetProperty.PropertyType) == null)
    {
        // Okay, trying to copy a null value into a non-nullable type.
        // Do whatever you want here
    }
    else
    {
        targetProperty.SetValue(target, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetProperty)` seems bad to me.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Sorry, meant to use `.PropertyType`. Fixed.

Comment: Do we really need both, `targetProperty.PropertyType.IsValueType &&
        Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetProperty.PropertyType) != null`? ___Edit:___ Ah, now I see, you say it is a value type _and_ it is not the special value type `Nullable<>`. All is good.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Whoops - it should actually be `== null`, at which point yes, we need both.

Comment: What would happen in the case both source and target properties _are_ `Nullable<T>`? I didn't expect this to be a real-life case but it turns out it is!

Comment: @Mr.Boy: Then I assume you'd want to set the value to be null, which is what the code I've shown will do.