# Getting null value when we copy non null-able property to null able property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was doing a deep copy of an object from object A to B but unable to copy non-nullable to nullable values. (I am copying Child object to Parent but it copying null value). How can we copy non-nullable to nullable?

Comment: possible solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638346/copy-a-nullable-property-to-a-non-nullable-version-using-reflection

Answer (score 0):

I referenced from this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638346/copy-a-nullable-property-to-a-non-nullable-version-using-reflection). With `reflection` you can do this:

```
var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
var destinationProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

object value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
    if (value == null && 
        targetProperty.PropertyType.IsValueType &&
        Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetProperty.PropertyType) == null)
    {
        // Code....
    }
    else
    {
        targetProperty.SetValue(target, value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your control for same type will fail in case (e.g) you are comparing a `int` member with a `Nullable<int>` (which you can write as `int?`) one (as expected, since they are not the same type.

You can use something like:

```
bool DestinationIsCompatible(Type source, Type destination)
{
    // null checks omitted...

    if (source == destination)
        return true;

    Type nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(destination);
    if (nullableType == source)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

and replace your control with

```
if (!DestinationIsCompatible(sourceProperty.PropertyType, destinationProperty.PropertyType)) continue;
```